# How to convert <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> to json in php?

Tags: php, asp.net, codeigniter

I find a problem to convert `<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">` to json in php, I try to look for an example but fail all.

This is my php script:

```
public function register() {
        $url = 'https://example.com/register';

        $post_data="Email=frank@email.com";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'));   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
```

and this is the response :

[image]

Please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post text as an image, it makes it impossible to copy/paste/test.

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange idea to send JSON in an XML document, but anyway.  Simplest (sensible way) is to load it with SimpleXML and then the JSON is just the text of the root node...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
echo (string)$xml;
```

should give

```
[
    {
    "CreateDate": "123"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nigel's comment that it's strange to embed JSON in XML, but IMO his solution plays a bit fast and loose with the assumed simplicity of the input. Also, DOMDocument and family tend to be a lot easier to use as far as PHP's XML libs go.

```php
$in = <<<_E_
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.com/">[
    {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
]</string>
_E_;

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadxML($in);
$json = $doc->getElementsByTagName('string')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($json, $decoded);
```

Output:

```
string(24) "[
    {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
]"

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["foo"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
  }
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Would be interested in why you think my version *plays a bit fast and loose with the assumed simplicity of the input*

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find a solution, like this :

```
public function register() {
        $url = 'https://example.com/register';

        $post_data="Email=frank@email.com";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'));   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($result,'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $temp = json_decode($xml);
        $json = json_encode($temp[0]);
        echo $json;
    }
```

and it works;